# how to create a dataset with only two columns starting from a dictionary with an ID and list of values.

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I'm trying to figure out how to create a dataset where the first column consists of the 'ID' from the dictionary and the second column of the value from the list of the dictionary so that I can plot this with seaborn.

```
di = {'a' : [1,4,5], 'b' : [1,8],'c' : [56,100,5,568],'d' : [20,10,2],'e' : [1000,3,675]}
```

I would thus want somthing like this:

```
ID       Value
a        1
a        4
a        5
b        1
b        8
c        56
c        100
```

and so on..
For now I only have this piece of code which separates my ID and my value but still keeps my value as a list and not as the above given example of the result that I search for.

```
serie = pd.Series(di)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':serie.index, 'Value':serie.values})
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks! This does in fact solve my problem with the dataframe but still doesn't let me plot it with seaborn
I used the command: 
sns.swarmplot(x="ID", y="Value", data=lol)
for this but that only gives me an Error.
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: This actually solved it completely! Thanks a lot man! I'd give you an upvote but I don't have enough Reputation, When I do i'll come back to this question to give you the upvote! 
Thanks again man!!

Comment: Please feel free to accept the provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either structure the dictionary into a records-like list (basically a list of lists) to pass to the `pd.DataFrame.from_records` function:

```
lol = [list(zip([x]*len(y), y)) for x, y in di.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([x for y in lol for x in y], columns=['ID', 'Value'])
sns.swarmplot(x="ID", y="Value", data=df)
```

Or, you can use `pd.Series` and unwrap the lists inside the rows with the following:

```
df = pd.Series(di).apply(pd.Series).stack()
df = df.reset_index(level=0).‌​rename(columns=lambd‌​a x: 'ID' if x else 'Value')
sns.swarmplot(x="ID", y="Value", data=df)
```

Either should get you what you need.